# list index out of range Error Pygame How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

```
    window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not sure how to fix this I tried to fix it but I keep getting the same error

```
        # this makes the enemy move right and left
        def draw(self,window):
            self.move()
            if self.Walking + 1 >= 33:
                self.Walking = 0
            if self.vel > 0:
                window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking += 1
            else:
                window.blit(self.esleft[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking += 1
```

the class of the enemy

```
 # ---------------------------------------------- # this for bird my g LOl
 
    class bird:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,end):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.esright = [pygame.image.load("bird1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("bird2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("bird3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("bird4.png")
                              ]
            self.esleft = [pygame.image.load("b1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("b2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("b3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("b4.png")
                              ]
            self.esright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.esright]
            self.esleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.esleft]
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.distance = 80
            self.speed = 8
            self.vel = 3
            self.path = [x,end]
            self.Walking = 0
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            # enemys health
            self.health = 10
            self.soko = 0
            self.visible = True
        # this makes the enemy move right and left
        def draw(self,window):
            
            self.move()
            if self.Walking + 1 >= 33:
                self.Walking = 0
            elif self.vel > 0:
                window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking += 1
            else:
                window.blit(self.esleft[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking += 1

    # this moves the enemy left and right
        def move(self):
            if self.visible:
                if self.vel > 0:
                   if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                       self.x += self.vel
                   else:
                       self.vel = self.vel * -1
                       self.Walking = 0
                else:
                   if self.x - self.vel >  self.path[0]:
                       self.x += self.vel
                   else:
                       self.vel = self.vel * -1
                       self.Walking = 0
                    # the hit box for the enemy the health
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 70, 10)) # NEW
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 70 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
                self.hitbox = (self.x + 47, self.y + 31, 50, 72)

     
    # THIS PART MAKES  the enemy not scroll with the player
        def scroll(self,sx, sy):
            self.x += sx
            self.y += sy
            self.path[0] += sx
            self.path[1] += sx



    # define the enemy class
    black = (0,0,0)
    bird1 = bird(300,199,104,64,500)
    birds = [bird1]
```

fefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefesfefes

Comment: I think we need more information, can you print `self.esright` before `window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))` to see what it has and what should it have?

Comment: I added the full class of the object updatE*

Comment: put `print(self.esright.__len()__, self.Walking//3)` just before line `window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))` And show me the Output.

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute '_bird__len'

Comment: put `print(self.esright.__len__(), self.Walking//3)`
my mistake

Comment: wait this one [My bad this one](https://gyazo.com/0082a2a3399a63f0bc117324c230234c)

Comment: understood whats the problem let me write an answer for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `self.Walking//3` to `self.Walking % 4`
if you want it to be computed on each iteration like :
`0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1...etc`

Change `self.Walking//3` to `int(self.Walking / 4) % 4`
if you want it to be computed on each iteration like :
`0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1...etc`

Comment: [video](https://gyazo.com/9bd6c1dac1281b5d1b19a30500636b01)

Comment: Now you should start googling about pygames flickering problem.

Comment: Learn to break down problems into smaller parts and then figure out solutions for that smaller parts For example i said you to show output to figure out whats wrong then tried to figure out what we need then tried to figure out how can we achive desired results

Answer (score 1):

Try making your second if statement to be part of the elif like this I think

```
def draw(self,window):
        self.move()
        if self.Walking + 1 >= 33:
            self.Walking = 0
        elif self.vel > 0:
            window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.Walking += 1
        else:
            window.blit(self.esleft[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.Walking += 1
```

or try indenting your self.move() to a if, elif, else statements

Comment: still getting the same error `    window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking//3], (self.x,self.y))
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: try indenting your self.move() to a if, elif, else statements

Comment: yah tried that nothing happened still getting the same error

Comment: I think your self.esright[self.Walking//3] divided the number out of range because your list has 4 elements in the draw(self, window)